# excel - how to calculate area in single drag

Tags: excel

```
          LENGTH        
BREADTH   10    20  30
  10      100       
  20            
  30
```

Above is excel sheet data. 100 is calculate by a formula `=(A4*B3)` ie 10*10
I want to populate the answer in rest of the cells too. 
Means I just want to write the formula once, which I did and got value 100, and now I just want to drag and apply the same formula to every block.

This is what I get when I drag the cell, which is wrong calculation:

```
          LENGTH        
BREADTH   10    20      30
  10    100     2000    60000
  20    2000    4000000 2.4E+11
  30    60000   2.4E+11 5.76E+22
```

Comment: `=OFFSET($A$2,0,COLUMN()-1)*OFFSET($A$2,ROW()-2,0)`, assuming that the cell with "BREADTH" in it is `A2`. Note that this isn't at all resilient to new rows or columns being added before the header row/column.

Comment: not working. A4 is my breadth. I am not getting correct output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is set part of your formula to be static like so:

`=B$2*$A3`

The `$` prevents the value after it from changing when you drag or copy the formula, but the other value is free to change based on the cell reference.

Comment: Can you explain me how $ works in this case? how is it applying same formula differently row wise and column wise?

Comment: If you break it up `B$2` the column reference can change but the row stays at row 2.  So as you drag it will change to `C2,D2,E2` etc. and the other `$A2` the column reference stays the same, but the row changes.  So as you drag it will change to `A3,A4,A5` etc.  Therefore any cell will reference the correct #'s to multiply.  `A4*C2=600`